# Electrostatic potential map and local ionization map

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

What's the difference between electrostatic potential map and local ionization map?

I think that the main difference is that the electrostatic potential map doesn't take into account resonance (delocalization), but only electronegativity, therefore nucleophilicity or electrophilicity of a species is much better estimated by using the local ionization map. Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the local ionization map?

Comment: Huh? I've just started using Spartan and I couldn't find a neat explanation in the manual.

Comment: Ok, it's from Spartan; that's what I meant by "reference". I've never heard of it before, but now I have a starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The excellent [MultiWFN](http://sobereva.com/multiwfn/) is able to produce both functions and luckily, [a reference for it](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jcc.22885) has explanations for both as well:

## Electrostatic potential

According to the reference above,

> $$V_{tot}(r)
>     = V_{nu}(r) + V_{ele}(r)
>       = \sum_A \frac{Z_A}{|r - R_A|} - \int \frac{\rho(r')}{|r - r'|} dr'$$
>   This function measures the electrostatic interaction between a unit point charge placed at $r$ and the system of interest.
>   A positive (negative) value implies that current position is dominated
>   by nuclear (electronic) charges.
>   Molecular ESP has been widely used for prediction of nucleophilic and electrophilic sites for a long time.
>   It is also valuable in studying hydrogen bonds, halogen bonds, molecular recognitions, and the inter-molecular interaction of aromatics.

## Average local ionisation energy

Again, according to the reference above,

> $$\bar{I}(r)
>     = \frac{\sum_i \rho_i(r) |\epsilon_i|}{\rho(r)}$$
>   where $\rho_i(r)$ and $\epsilon_i$ are the electron density function and orbital energy of the $i$th molecular orbital, respectively.
>   This function has many uses, for example, reproducing atomic shell structure, measuring electronegativity, quantifying local polarizability and hardness, and predicting sites for electrophilic or radical attack.

Thus, while the **electrostatic potential** represents the hypothetical electrostatic *interaction energy between the molecule and a positive unit point charge at $r$*, the **average local ionisation energy** is the *orbital density-weighted absolute orbital energy average*.

Finally, resonance/delocalization/electronegativity are built in the method you use to produce the electron density $\rho(r)$ (*edit*: a nice discussion about it can be found [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00894-015-2585-5)).